# Accessing functions in package made using poetry

Tags: python, package, python-poetry

I am wanting to package my python code using poetry. I have managed to make a .whl which I can install using pip, but when I import it in python I cannot access any of the functions.

This is my current `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "package"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "package description"
authors = ["Andrew"]
packages = [{include = "package"}]
include = ["package/helper.py", 
           "package/scheduler.py"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^3.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=0.12"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"
```

in the package directory that poetry created there is 3 files: `helper.py`, `scheduler.py` and `__init__.py`. Inside `helper.py` there is a function called `adder(x,y)`.

I want to be able to call this function in python, how do I have to modify my .toml file to do this? I have tried various variations of the packages and include arguments but nothing has worked so far. Thanks

Comment: after installing it, did you import the module properly with `import package; package.helper.adder(1, 2)`?

Comment: Your pyproject file looks a little unusual. You normally don't need to specify `packages` or `include`, because the code will be in a folder with the same name as the package, which allows poetry to autodetect it. Consider running `poetry new <package_name>` in a different folder and copying your existing code over into that one. That should get rid of these kinds of project structure problems.

Comment: I think that has solved it, thank you Arne. I think I was just getting confused on how to properly make the .toml

Comment: no problem, glad I could help